# Trick for seeing databound list controls in the VS XAML Editor

Tags: silverlight, xaml, editor

Is there any way to see what a control will look like in the XAML designer when it's ItemSource property is databound?  I want to see what it looks like in the designer somehow without actually running the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good article by Karl Shifflett that explains how to display design-time data :
http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/viewing-design-time-data-in-visual-studio-2008-cider-designer-in-wpf-and-silverlight-projects/

WPF 4 will come with native support of design-time data